# inserting a pdf file in the same latex page

Tags: pdf, latex

I have a pdf file that contains a diagram. The pdf page is about 33*7 and I want to insert it within the same page of what I wrote in Latex but when I use `\includepdf[pages=-]{sysar.pdf}` it inserts into a new page with the diagram in the middle and the rest of the page is blank.

Comment: Well, you may use `\includegraphics[width=...]{sysar.pdf}` is there is only one page. (Load the `graphicx` package.)

Comment: Can you add a bit more information to your question about what you are trying to do? Are you inserting just one page or multiple pages? How should the result look like?

Comment: It has one page only. \includegraphics worked. Thank you!